# npm run dev not recognizing new sass division format

Tags: npm, sass

In order to prepare for Dart Sass 2.0.0, I'm following these instructions to migrate the current divisions in my scss files, from slashes to the function "divide": https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div

The migration works well as I don't get anymore warnings about using slashes.

The problem comes when I run `npm run dev` after that, giving me the following error: `SassError: Undefinied operation "divide"`

Should I upgrade something else so npm doesn't complain about the "divide" functions?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that when doing the migration, it substitutes all the instructions that contain `/` by `Math.div()` and there are some which are not divisions, but rather text concatenation.

Line before executing the migration:

```
background: $custom-select-background, $custom-select-bg escape-svg($icon) $custom-select-feedback-icon-position / $custom-select-feedback-icon-size no-repeat;
```

Line after executing the migration:

```
background: $custom-select-background, $custom-select-bg escape-svg($icon) math.div($custom-select-feedback-icon-position, $custom-select-feedback-icon-size) no-repeat;
```

To fix it simply replace line 120 of the file `node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_forms.scss` with the following line:

```
background: $custom-select-background, $custom-select-bg escape-svg($icon) $custom-select-feedback-icon-position / $custom-select-feedback-icon-size no-repeat;
```

In the following link you can see more information about the error. https://github.com/sass/migrator/issues/205

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1330

You need to use `math.div()` e.g. `math.div(12px, 4px); // 3`

Examples of use here https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div

If you are suddenly getting this issue, and don't want to go through all your code, you could check the [semver](https://semver.org/) of SASS being used. It is probably using the caret `^`, and if you use tilde instead,  `~` it should prevent the breaking patch being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply automatic migration for all your sass files, via [sass-migrator](https://github.com/sass/migrator#readme)

simpy do a

```
npm install -g sass-migrator
sass-migrator division **/*.scss
```

If you want to apply all math.div() and list.slash() migrations in all your sass files, simple link your entry file containing all imports, then add the option `--migrate-deps`.

An example of that

```
sass-migrator division style.scss --migrate-deps
```

Source: [Sass Docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div)